# I have a question.about scala list partition by envn index

Tags: scala

it is a partitioned by index number
ex) `split(List(3, 6, 4, 2, 1))`

```
(List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(3, 4, 1),List(6, 2))
```

my code is

```
(list.zipWithIndex.partition(_._2%2==0)._1.map({ case (x, y) =>  (x) }))
```

but i can't do anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Scala 2.13.x then you can use `partitionMap()`.

```
List(3, 6, 4, 2, 1)
  .zipWithIndex
  .partitionMap(t =>
     if (t._2 % 2 < 1) Left(t._1) else Right(t._1))

//res0: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(3, 4, 1),List(6, 2))
```